# Create MySQL Table from pandas dataframe - error 1054 (42S22)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have a dataframe `df` created as follow :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(product_urlList, nameList, priceList, picList)), 
               columns =['URL','NomProduit', 'Prix', "LienPic"])

df['IdUnique'] = df['NomProduit'] + df['Prix']
```

My target is to import it into a MySQL database.

I created an SQL Database (called "Sezane")  and its table called "Robes" via Python with MySQL.connector.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "password",
    database = "sezane"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Robes (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Nom_Robes VARCHAR(255), Prix_Robes VARCHAR(255), liens_Robes VARCHAR(300), Images_robes VARCHAR (300), Id_Robes VARCHAR (255))'
```

Then, I try to insert this dataframe in the table :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@Localhost:3306/sezane', echo=True)
df.to_sql(name='Robes', con=engine, if_exists = 'append')
```

I have the following error :

```
ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'
```

I made some researches about this error and found that it could become a problem of quote bracket "/' interversion.

However, after many hours on it, I still don't understand where it comes from. Why is the error message about "Index" ?

My target is to be able to make my `df` as a table.

Comment: Could you give an example of the actual `df` you're trying to stuff into a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) tries to export the dataframe index as a column. You should be able to change this:
`df.to_sql(name='Robes', con=engine, if_exists = 'append')`

To this:
`df.to_sql(name='Robes', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)` and you will no longer get the same error.